Required Intel CPU Video Driver
I need a Intel Video Driver to run latest OBS Studio on Debian 12. I have installed: mesa, mesa-utils, xserver-xorg-video-intel, intel-media-va-driver. My CPU is Intel Core i5 (i5-560m)
What's the next packages to install ?
